# Writing functions in R: paste name of statistic (as a variable) as column name

Tags: r, function, variables, paste

I am writing a function in which I want to vary the statistic of interest (mean, median, standard deviation). Is it possible to take the name of the statistic and add it to the column name? Here is what I am attempting:

```
DRG_stats_function <- function(df, statistic){
  df %>%
    group_by(Code) %>%
    summarize(across(Payments, statistic)) %>%
    knitr::kable(col.names = c('Code', paste0(statistic, 'of Payments')))
}
```

I would like the titles of the columns to be "Code" and "Mean of Payments"/"Median of Payments"/"Standard Deviation of Payments".

I've tried str(statistic), deparse(substitute()), as_label(), and what seems like many others.

Answer (score 1):

Using `deparse` + `substitute` should work.

```
library(dplyr)

DRG_stats_function <- function(df, statistic){

  column_name <- deparse(substitute(statistic))
  df %>%
    group_by(Code) %>%
    summarize(across(Payments, statistic)) %>%
    knitr::kable(col.names = c('Code', paste0(column_name, 'of Payments')))
}

DRG_stats_function(data, median)
```

However, you don't need `across` if you are applying the function on only one column (`Payments`)

```
DRG_stats_function <- function(df, statistic){
  column_name <- deparse(substitute(statistic))
  df %>%
    group_by(Code) %>%
    summarize(!!paste(column_name, 'of Payments') := statistic(Payments)) %>%
    knitr::kable()
}
```

Comment: `across()` also has a `.names` argument so you can do it in that line.

Comment: Yes, that's true but in this case I think we don't need `across` at all since we are applying the function only on one column.

Comment: Great - thanks! I was attempting to put the deparse(substitute()) in the paste function, but it worked when I split it out.